# Acceptance requirements for PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am a European student accepted for a PhD at an Ivy league University with scholarship. Extremely happy about that, but I have now become very stressed that the admission might be withdrawn.

In the admission letter there is a general requirement to send transcripts from prior institutions. I have a bachelor degree, and with transcripts sent in as part of the application. I am in the process of finalising a Master's degree, but I will not be awarded the degree before the PhD program starts. This is due to an administrative issue: the university had told me that my class schedule would meet the requirements for a master's, but then changed their mind after classes had begun.

When looking at the admission requirements of the university the minimum requirements are Bachelor's degree and language requirements so I feel that it will not be a problem. But I have written in my application that I am doing a Master's.

Will a missed Master's affect my admission to the university or is the Bachelor degree sufficient?

Comment: What does it mean that the university made an error when registering your courses?

Comment: They told me that taking a set of courses would make me eligible for a master's degree, but later changed their mind. The important thing is not if they will give me the master (which they won't), but if it is required that I complete it before starting the PhD

Comment: It's entirely up to the program you applied to.

Comment: You'll find that the US is in general much less bureaucratic and attached to formal requirements than Europe.  You might find this maddening or a breathe of fresh air or both.

Comment: Basically, it seems you are asking if your matriculation is conditional on the acceptable completion of your Masters, successful completion of the courses in which you are currently enrolled, or neither. We current faculty can tell you what our individual department policies on this would be and our general sense of what would be reasonable, but we can't speak for the institution where you are accepted. It seems this is best answered by them.

Answer (score 4):

No, most doctoral programs in the US don't require a masters to start, though some offer one along the way. If the program you have been accepted for says that a bachelors is sufficient then it meets this common practice. There are some exceptions to this rule, as the US doesn't have a uniform system of higher education other than in broad outline.

But you still need to send the masters-level transcripts, which give courses and such, though it won't show (and doesn't need to show) completion of the degree. Transcripts of all prior higher education is also a normal requirement in the US.

The reason that an offer *might* be withdrawn would normally be based on some academic misconduct of the candidate that occurs and comes to light. But that isn't what you describe.

Comment: Thank you, I can sleep a little lighter tonight. This means that the normal process after I accept a offer is that I need to ask my university to send my bachelor's degree, and my grades from the master courses I took (likely around april/may), and that universities don't usually ask you to resend proof of master's degree after that is accepted in june/july?

Comment: @pulsesc If you said you'd have a master's degree when you applied, it'd be perfectly reasonable for them to expect to see that you have a master's degree.

Comment: I did not say I had a master's degree, but I registered that I was in the process of obtaining it, including adding my grades.

Comment: @BryanKrause, the OP has said they are "doing a MS", not that they possess one. Ergo, no issue.

Comment: @Buffy I assumed that OP meant that they would have completed their masters before starting the PhD, otherwise why would they be concerned now that they will not complete that degree?

Comment: @pulsesc Not that you have one, but presumably you indicated you *would* have one.

Comment: @BryanKrause, nobody could guarantee the truth of such a statement.

Comment: @Buffy I'm not sure that I follow. It's normal for applicants to graduate school to have degrees in-progress, since the admissions process usually occurs (at least in the US) in the middle of the school year. That's why final transcripts are not required at the time of application but some time later, instead. A student should be able to predict what degree they will have by the time they matriculate.

Comment: I think the crux here is that the OP will be short one or two courses and will not receive the masters degree by the time they matriculate. I would guess most PhD programs would not be upset about this, but the OP should be candid about this with director of the program to get an official “this is fine” email.

Comment: I agree, this seems like a question that should be closed rather than answered. It may be that OP was admitted specifically because they were on track to complete a master's; in this case, the lack of a master's may well be a problem (especially if it seems likely that similar problems will recur during the PhD). Or it may be that OP was admitted because of their undergraduate work, and no one cares about the master's at all. Only the program in question can answer.